# distribution involving Dirac Delta function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, problem-solving, uniform-distribution

Let $T\sim~U[-t_0,t_0]$. Then I define random variable $R$ as the following

$\mathbb{P}\{R=t|T=t\}=\beta$ and $\mathbb{P}\{R\neq t|T=t\}=1-\beta$.

My first question is: Why we can write the conditional density as

$f(R=r|T=t)=(1-\beta)+\beta\delta(t-r)$, **or actually, we should write is as $f(R=r|T=t)=\frac{1-\beta}{2t_0}+\beta\delta(t-r)$???**

where $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Dirac Delta function such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)=1$ and $\delta(x)=0$ if $x\neq 0$ and $\delta(x)=\infty$ if $x=0$?

I understand that if $t\neq r$, then $f(R=r|T=t)=1-\beta$, which looks the same as $\mathbb{P}\{R\neq t|T=t\}=1-\beta$. But if $r=t$, then how $f(R=r|T=t)=(1-\beta)+\beta\delta(t-r)$ connects to $\mathbb{P}\{R=t|T=t\}=\beta$?

My second question is: what is the marginal distribution of $R$? Should it be

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
f(R=r)&=\int_{-t_0}^{t_0}f(R=r|T=t)f_T(t)dt\\
&=\int_{-t_0}^{t_0}[(1-\beta)+\beta\delta(t-r)]f_T(t)dt\\
&=(1-\beta)+\beta\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-r)f_T(t)dt\\
&=1-\beta+\beta\frac{\mathbf{1}_{\{-t_0\leq r\leq t_0\}}}{2t_0}??
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Is the last step correct? I use the property $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\delta(t-T)dt=f(T)$.

What is the support of $R$ is? In the above density, it seems that if we integrate over $[-\infty,\infty]$, then the integral of $f_R(r)$ won't be one. So it is not a valid density function?

I did a simulation study

1. Generate $M$ i.i.d. $U[-2,2]$ $T_i$
2. For each $T_i$, generate one $U[0,1]$, if it is less than $\beta=0.6$, then set $R_i=T_i$, otherwise, set $R_i=U[-z_0,z_0]$.
3. Plot the density of $R_i$, it is indeed $f_R(r)=\frac{1}{2t_0}=0.25$. And this density is independent of $\beta$.

So this means, my above derivation is wrong??

Comment: Why do you change the bounds of integration to $-\infty$ and $\infty$?

Comment: @TonyS.F. I just want to make it more like the textbook example... I don't know Delta function quite well. In addition, as $f_T(t)=1/(2t_0)$ when $t\in[-t_0,t_0]$ and $f_T(t)=0$ otherwise, so I see no harm to change the bounds of integration to $-\infty$ and $\infty$, correct?

Comment: @TonyS.F. I kind of see your point.... currently, this $f_R(r)$ does not integrate to 1, if you consider $r\in[-\infty, \infty]$. Where does my derivation go wrong?

Comment: You don't have to change the bounds. There's no harm but you should never do stuff like that if you don't have to. We don't know that integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ even makes sense without more work. You wouldn't write $\leq$ if you knew two numbers were equal. All that matter for the delta function is that the region you integrate over contains a point that makes the argument $0$, in this case since $r\in[-t_0,t_0]$ you have nothing to worry about. If you don't contain such a point then the integral will just be $0$ identically.